# Enable C++ comments for C in Eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse, comments

I there a way to make Eclipse "recognize" C++ comments when writing C code.
I mean that I'd like Eclipse to continue C++ comments on new lines.
In other words that:

```
// My comment<Enter>
```

produces

```
// My comment
// <cursor>
```

Thanks!

Comment: How could the editor possibly know that you intend to continue your comment?

Comment: "line comments" are called like that for a reason. If you want to comment on multiple lines, "multi-line" comments might be better and many editors support some fancy continuation-formatting for them.

Comment: Many IDEs when presented with `/** My comment <Enter>` will do what you want. But with a multiline comment. Which is what you should do since you are actually writing a comment across multiple lines.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: I have been a heavy Vim user for years and that is something pretty natural for me now since it is a basic Vim feature!

Comment: @Olaf: I noticed that Eclipse continues the multi line comments. But I am not used to them... I'll try to change my mind then!

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos: It works but this comments are the beginning of Doxygen documentation blocks. Since I use it in my project, I can't use those `/**` for something else!

Comment: @Plouff: Perhaps a good time to start using doxygen:-) Personal remark: I very seldom use non-doxygen comments over multiple lines. In the code, a single line should be sufficient. If you frequently need more to explain what the code does, you should step back and think it over. It is often an indicator of bad choise of names, bad structure, etc. Perhaps a function would be better (a good compiler inlines `static` functions used only once), etc.

Comment: Oh, and - in case you did not already notice - These are called line-comment, not C++ comments. They are standard part of the C language since C99. (They just originate from C++, but some compilers allow(ed) them for C90, too before C99 was released.)

Comment: @Olaf: It was probably not clear enough: I already use Doxygen :)! Regarding your personal remark: Do you write plain english comments or not? What is your limit of characters per line (mine is 80)? With 80 char and plain english, I often feel I need multi line comments! I think my variable and function names are not that bad. At least I try to think about those names!

Comment: @Olaf: Thanks for the history of comments in C standard ;)! I really thought they were C++ comments so non standard from C but supported by compilers. Its good to know this is not the case.

Comment: I do code in English and restrict to ca.80 chars. Comments are very short normally, often shorter than my native language would be. Just look at some coding standards for naming. But remember: no rule without exceptions.

Comment: Ok. I may need to learn to be less verbose with comments... I tend to write long sentence in plain English. Thanks for sharing your experience!